# Convert Military Hours to Normal Hours

Tags: javascript

I'd like my hours section to be set to 1–12 and not 0–23. Thank you.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
   setInterval(function(){ time();}, 1000)

function time(){
 var dates = new Date();

 var newDates = dates.toDateString();
 // var clock = dates.toLocaleTimeString();
 var seconds = dates.getSeconds();
 var minutes = dates.getMinutes();
 var hours = dates.getHours();
 var stringSeconds= String(seconds);
 var stringMinutes= String(minutes);
 var stringHours= String(hours);
 newDate.textContent = newDates;
 newDivSeconds.textContent =  stringSeconds;
 newDivMinutes.textContent = stringMinutes + '   :' ;
 newDivHours.textContent = stringHours + '   :';
```

Comment: @aryamccarthy -- No, I think the system time is grabbed at a single moment, the `new Date()` at the beginning.

Comment: Have you not tried an `if (hours > 12)` type test?

Answer (score 3):

```
const usHours = (date.getHours() % 12) || 12;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [modulus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) operator

```
var usHours = date.getHours() % 12;
```

Comment: This puts values in the range 0–11, not 1–12.